# .mouseleave not working with "if" statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, mouseenter, mousehover

I have a navigation menu.I want it to change the opacity to 1 when i hover the cursor over it then IF the page is scrolled down and mouse is no longer hovering over it decrease opacity to 0.5.
I have this jQuery code :

```
  // JavaScript Document
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


  var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;

  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPos > navOffset) {
      jQuery("nav").stop(true);
      jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
      jQuery("nav").fadeTo(1000, 0.5);

    } else {
      jQuery("nav").stop(true);
      jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
      jQuery("nav").fadeTo(1000, 1.0);
    }

   });

   $("nav").mouseenter(function(){
       jQuery("nav").stop(true);
      jQuery("nav").fadeTo(1000,1.0);  
     });


  jQuery("nav").mouseleave(function(){
      if (scrollPos > navOffset) {
       jQuery(this).stop(true);
       jQuery(this).fadeTo(1000,0.5);
      }
      });

});
```

And this CSS code :

```
.fixed { 
position:fixed;
top:0;
}
```

When i hover the mouse it works but when i no longer hover over it and my page is scrolled down, wont return to his opacity.Thank you for any help that you can give.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to see the problem without a working jsfiddle, which would greatly help SO users try and figure out what is wrong with the code sample.

However, it looks like the root of the problem is with testing `scrollPos`, which is only defined within the scope of the `scroll` event handler. Therefor, in the `mouseleave` event handler, the variable `scrollPos` is not defined (as you could also see in the javascript console).

You could make `scrollPos` a variable defined within the scope of the `document.ready` handler; However, a better approach in my opinion would be to define a small function that checks whether the scroll offset is beyond the nav offset. The code would look something like this:

```
function checkOffset(){
  return $(window).scrollTop()>$("nav").offset().top;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (checkOffset()) {
      $("nav").stop(true).addClass("fixed").fadeTo(1000, 0.5);
    } else {
      $("nav").stop(true).removeClass("fixed").fadeTo(1000, 1.0);
    }
  });

  $("nav").mouseenter(function(){
    $("nav").stop(true).fadeTo(1000,1.0);  
  });

  $("nav").mouseleave(function(){
    if (checkOffset()) {
      $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(1000,0.5);
    }
  });
});
```